# CSS parent and child extend page with content

Tags: html, css

Now I have seen this same question all around but they are all different. One is for floats, the other for three different divs. This is just a parent and a child. It's very simple yet I'm doing something wrong. This is what the site layout looks like:

[image: Layout]

Here is the HTML:

```
<body> 
 <div id="header">
  <?php include("../includes/navbar.php"); ?>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
 </div>

 <div id="main"> 
  <div id="main-container">
    test<br>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer">
  <?php include("../includes/footer.php"); ?>
 </div>
</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
html, body, ul, p { 
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight:200;
}
#header {
position:fixed;
background:#222;
color:#999;
width:100%;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
top:0;
z-index:1;
height:5%;
}
#main {
margin-top:2.4%;
background:#f0f0f0;
position:relative;
padding:0;
width:100%;
color:#222;
min-height:100%;
height: auto;
overflow:hiden;
}
#main-container{
background:#fff;
word-wrap:break-word;
margin-right:15%;
margin-left:15%;
border-left:3px solid #d5d5d5;
border-right:3px solid #d5d5d5;
border-bottom-right-radius:50px 50px;
border-bottom-left-radius:50px 50px;
min-height: 100%;
color:#222;
}
#footer {
font: 20px Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
text-align:center;
width:100%;
height:10%;
color: #222;
text-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #555;
background:#474747;
}
```

Now with those codes above if the content runs past the bottom of the page the `#main` and `#content` will keep going until the end of the content. The problem is while `#main` has a height on auto the `#content` stops once it reaches the end of the content. I want it to extend to the end of the page just like `#main` does but when there is more content then it keeps going tell the content ends.

It's for me to explain so sorry if you can't understand it.

Comment: Got an example with sticky footer: http://jsbin.com/ibudus/1/edit - but it does not look pretty because the main content does not take all of the available height. Good read: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page/

Comment: @Alp Ya, it's frustrating. I have looked at that link before never got it to work. If I did, do you think it will help with the main and main-container?

Comment: My example follows that instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/5PE8c/3/)**

### Markup

```
<div id="header">
<h1>Main Title of Web Page</h1></div>
<div id="main">

<div id="main-content">
Content</div>
 </div>
<div id="footer" style="background-color:#FFA500;clear:both;text-align:center;">
Copyright © something</div>
```

### CSS

```
#main
{
    height: 100%;
    background: pink;
    margin: -37px 100px -20px 100px;
    padding: 37px 0 20px 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#main-content {
    overflow:auto;
    height:100%;
    min-height: 100%;  
}
#header
{
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
    height: 37px;
    background:orange;
}
#footer
{
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it this you want?

JSFiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/GWESn/1/)

I have added this to your main-container, this way it always fills up your div to the top & bottom of the parent div:

```
#main-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 70%;
}
```

I hope this helps :) otherwise, I didn't really understand the question very well.

---

EDIT: the problem with this approach was that the

```
position:absolute;
```

rule on the child, caused the parent not to be filled to the bottom of the child, causing the relative footer not to float after the #main div.
I adjusted alp's example [Here](http://jsbin.com/ibudus/5/edit). Using only relative divs, I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Almost. The only problem is then if it runs over then the footer and the main just stay still and the main-container keeps going.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean.. Can you explain further?

Comment: Ill try :P. When I put that in, the main-container is always extended to the bottom of the page just like main. That's good but then if the content extends further than the page the footer and main stay still and the main-content keeps going. I want them all to go down the page as one. If you need me try to make more sense I could try again or just make some pictures :).

Comment: I understand now :D I'll try to add it to the fiddle

Comment: Alright I've been working on this all day, I really don't like CSS :P I'm more of a PHP guy.